# How to disable building R packages from source?

Tags: r, gcc, build, compilation, rstudio

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and some time ago I turned on building R packages from source. I did it because one of the packages I wanted to use didn't work properly when it wasn't compiled locally. Now I'm a bit fed up with the lengthy process of building from source so I want to turn it off. Compiling works fine but it takes too much time. I couldn't find any instructions about disabling it.

How to stop building R packages from source?

Comment: presumably this is being done in Rstudio?

Comment: yes. I use RStudio.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, installing packages from R run from the command line will ask about this. See also the `type` argument in `install.packages`

Comment: Where are you going to get binary R packages for Ubuntu from?

Comment: @Spacedman: CRAN. @MichaelChirico: I checked the documentation of `install.packages` and used `options(install.packages.check.source = "both")` as suggested in the Binary packages section. This didn't help and the packages still seem to be built with g++

Comment: CRAN does not have binaries for ubuntu, because it would be too difficult to build for every flavour of Ubuntu and all the other Linux distros too. c2d4u might work [https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u] but then you install with `apt` as admin, not `install.packages` as a user.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u is the link. Don't know why SO put an extra ] on the end...

Comment: @Spacedman I'm a bit lost now. So are you saying that I always have to build packages from source on Ubuntu if I'm getting them from CRAN? Thanks for the link to c2d4u.

Comment: Yes. There are no Ubuntu binaries (or Linux binaries) of packages on CRAN. Never have been.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks. Please put your comments about the lack of Linux binaries and c2d4u as an answer so that I can accept it.